# Sticky header script doesn't account for variable height of window

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have a sticky header that utilizes the process found here (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp). This works great. However, this does not account for variable heights of the hero element above the header. When you resize the window vertically, the sticky header breaks until you refresh the browser. What do I need to add to the script so that it detects the new height upon resizing?

Here is a codepen displaying my dilemma: https://codepen.io/JKDESIGN44/pen/VwYBqBV

Here is the javascript:

```
// STICKY HEADER

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // When the event DOMContentLoaded occurs, it is safe to access the DOM

  // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
  window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);

  // Get the navbar
  var navbar = document.getElementById("c3Header");

  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. 
  // Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position

  function myFunctionForSticky() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      console.log("window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
    } else {
      console.log("Not window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you need to support IE11? If not, then you don't need any JS and you can achieve a sticky header with pure CSS [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702402/i-want-to-make-a-header-that-freezes/59702968#59702968)

Comment: That is a good solution, but I would probably like to have support for IE11 as well. I will probably use that solution if there are no other options.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any JS to accomplish this. All you need are two lines of css to be able to accomplish the same, with way less complexity.

Take a look at this:

```css
html, body, header{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.full-height-section{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: inherit;
}

li{
 list-style-type: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.bg-aqua{
 background-color: #073038;
}

.text-white{
 color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  font-family: 
}

.text-hover-blue:hover{
 color: #7DD2EF;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}


/* --------------HEADER---- */

/* ----HERO---- */

.hero{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 min-height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.hero-text{
 font-size: 40px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index: 20;
}

.content-hero{
 height: 25vh;
 width: 100vw;
 min-height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.hero-bg{
 display: block;
 object-fit: cover;
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 500px;
}

.hero-logo-wrap{
 align-self: center;
 height: 30vw;
 max-height: 50vh;
 min-height: 200px;
 z-index: 10;
}

.hero-logo{
 height: 100%;
}

.down-arrow-wrapper{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto; 
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 40px;
 border-radius: 999px;
 background-color: rgba(125,210,239,0.0);
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 z-index: 10;
}

.down-arrow-wrapper:hover{
 background-color: rgba(125,210,239,1.0);
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transform: scale(1.2)
}


.down-arrow-rel-wrapper{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 position: relative;
}

.down-arrow{
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto; 
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 8px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 border-right: solid #fff 3px;
 border-bottom: solid #fff 3px;
}

.img-overlay{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 mix-blend-mode: overlay;
 
 background: rgb(3,31,36);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(148deg, rgba(3,31,36,1) 0%, rgba(125,210,239,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(148deg, rgba(3,31,36,1) 0%, rgba(125,210,239,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(148deg, rgba(3,31,36,1) 0%, rgba(125,210,239,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#031f24",endColorstr="#7dd2ef",GradientType=1);
}

/* ----HERO END---- */


.header{
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
}

.content-header{
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .page-wrapper{
 padding-top: 150px;
}

.nav-flexbox{
 height: 150px;
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 1500px;
 min-width: 1000px;
 position: relative;
/*
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
*/
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.nav-left{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 width: 100%;
}

.nav-center{
 width: 70%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.header-logo{
 height: 80px;
 z-index: 999;
}

.header-logo-link{
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header-logo-link:hover{
 transform: scale(1.2);
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.nav-right{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 width: 100%;
}

.tab-nav-center{
 display: none;
}

.tab-nav-right{
 display: none;
}


.content-sub-nav{
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-content: center;
}

.sub-nav-arrow {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  
  border-bottom: 30px solid #031F24;
  
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}


/* ---------------HEADER END---- */

.content-section{
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<header>
  
<!----------------
 HERO
------------------>
  
  <div class="hero full-height-section">
   
   <div class="hero-logo-wrap"> 
    <img src="http://c3.abettermancc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Primary-Logo_Vertical.png" class="hero-logo">
   </div>
   
   <a href="#c3Header">
   
    <div class="down-arrow-wrapper">
     
     <div class="down-arrow">
      
     </div>
     
    </div>
   
   </a>
   
   <img src="http://c3.abettermancc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/audience-black-and-white-black-and-white-2014773.jpg" class="hero-bg full-height-section">
<!--------------Overlay -->
   <div class="bg-aqua" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;
    margin: auto; top: 0; opacity: 0.7; z-index: 9;">
   </div>
   <div class="img-overlay" style="z-index: 9;">
   </div>
<!--------------Overlay END -->
   
  </div>
  
<!----------------
 HERO END
------------------>
  
 </header>
 
<!----------------
 NAVIGATION
------------------>
  
 <nav class="header bg-aqua text-white" id="c3Header">
  
  <div class="nav-flexbox">
  
   <div class="nav-left">
    <a href="" class="text-hover-blue"><li>who we are</li></a>
    <a href="" class="text-hover-blue"><li>ministries</li></a>
    <a href="" class="text-hover-blue"><li>sermons</li></a>
   </div>
   
   
    <div class="nav-center">
     <a href="#" class="header-logo-link">
      <img src="http://c3.abettermancc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Primary-Icon-01.png" class="header-logo">
     </a>
    </div>
 
   
   <div class="nav-right">
    <a href="" class="text-hover-blue"><li>get connected</li></a>
    <a href="" class="text-hover-blue"><li>events</li></a>
    <a href="" class="text-hover-blue"><li>give online</li></a>
   </div>
  
  </div>
  
 </nav>
  
<!----------------
 NAVIGATION END
------------------>

<div class="content-section" style="background-color: #888888;">
  <p>SECTION 1</p>
</div>

<div class="content-section" style="background-color: #999999;">
  <p>SECTION 2</p>
</div>

<div class="content-section" style="background-color: #888888;">
  <p>SECTION 3</p>
</div>
```

The trick was adding:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

To the `.header` class. The `top:0` states that this class content will only get sticky when it reaches 0 offset from the top (meaning, just at the top of the page).

Comment: You'll also need to add `position: -webkit-sticky` for Safari, but yes this is the way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that, I'm too used to ignore certain browsers these days...

Comment: I like this solution. But is there anyway workaround for IE11?

Comment: It also doesn't seem to be working on mobile. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: In IE11 you really have to do some work with JS, like you did in your solution.Mobile wise, it seems to be working nicely on chrome at least (where I tested).